# I want to rerun "ready" event of polymer-element under dom-if template

Tags: javascript, polymer

if child element is visible under "dom-if" template,
I want to rerun "ready" event of the child element.

are there any tips to rerun "ready" event of the child element?

The code is like below.
in this case, I want to rerun "ready" event of owl-element

```js
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isPlugin(config.plugin,'owl')}}" id="owl">
    <owl-element html$="{{config.html}}" autoplay-speed$="{{config.speed}}" tranisition$="{{config.transition}}" on-box-update="gotoNextBox">
    </owl-element>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you try using dom-change event on your dom-if? https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-change

Comment: This might not be related your case. Dom-if just hides element from the dom, but not destroy it. This is due to faster operation. You can add a 'restamp'-attribute to dom-if, which makes the dom-if elements recreate everytime it displays. Example: <template is="dom-if" if="{{isPlugin(config.plugin,'owl')}}" id="owl" restamp>

Comment: Thank you !!!
I didn't know about "restamp"

Comment: I can recreate elements and rerun ready events Thank u !!

Comment: @steelydylan, I copied my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dom-if just hides element from the dom, but not destroy it. This is due to faster operation. You can add a 'restamp'-attribute to dom-if, which makes the dom-if elements recreate everytime it displays.

Example:

```
 <template is="dom-if" if="{{isPlugin(config.plugin,'owl')}}" id="owl" restamp>
```